# Custom Exception ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public class CustomExceptionHandlerFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "Exception"
            };
        }
    }

public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new CustomExceptionHandlerFilter());
        }



 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            RegisterDependencyResolution();
            InitializeAutoMapper();
        }
```

CONTROLLER CLASS

```
 [HttpPost]
        [CustomExceptionHandlerFilter]
        public ActionResult New(PurchaseInvMasterModel model)
        {
            //try
            //{

                int companyid = int.Parse(((UserIdentity)User.Identity).CompanyId);

                using (SalesMgmtEntities dbCon = new SalesMgmtEntities())
                {

                    model.PaymentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DueDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(); ;
                    model.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(model.Date, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
                    var inv = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PurchaseInvMasterModel, PurchaseInvMaster>(model);

                    inv.CustomerId = model.CustomerId;
                    var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerById(model.CustomerId);
                    inv.DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.DueDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    inv.Code = GetCode();
                    inv.AmountInWords = model.AmountInWords;
                    inv.TotalAmount = model.TotalAmount;
                    inv.NetAmount = model.TotalAmount;
                    inv.InvoiceAmount = model.InvoiceAmount;

                    inv.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(model.Date);
                    inv.IsActive = true;
                    inv.CreatedBy = ((UserIdentity)User.Identity).Name;
                    inv.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    inv.ModifiedBy = ((UserIdentity)User.Identity).Name;
                    inv.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    inv.CompanyId = companyid;
                    inv.InvoiceType = model.InvoiceType;
                    inv.Status = "S";
                    inv.CustomerNotes = model.CustomerNotes;
                    inv.TermsAndConditions = model.TermsAndConditions;
                    inv.TransportFreight = model.TransportFreight;
                    dbCon.PurchaseInvMasters.Add(inv);
                    dbCon.SaveChanges();

                    string businesCode = ((UserIdentity)User.Identity).BusinessCode;

                    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    IEnumerable<PurchaseInvDetailModel> detail = js.Deserialize<IEnumerable<PurchaseInvDetailModel>>(model.DetailString);

                    foreach (var item in detail)
                    {
                        PurchaseInvDetail d = new PurchaseInvDetail();

                        d.MasterId = inv.Id;
                        d.IsActive = true;
                        d.Date = DateTime.Now;
                        d.Description = item.Description;
                        d.TaxId = item.TaxId;
                        d.Qty = item.Qty;
                        d.Rate = item.Rate;
                        d.InventoryId = item.InventoryId;
                        d.Discount = item.Discount;
                        d.DiscountType = item.DiscountType;
                        d.Amount = item.Amount;

                        var quantity = _stockService.GetStockById(item.InventoryId).Quantity - item.Qty;
                        _stockService.UpdateStock(new Stock { ProductID = item.InventoryId, Quantity = quantity });

                        if (businesCode == "02")
                        {
                            d.BatchNo = item.BatchNo;
                            d.ExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Expiry, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                            d.Bonus = item.Bonus;
                        }

                        db.PurchaseInvDetails.Add(d);
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return JsonResponse("Record saved succussfully.",
                        status: AjaxResponseStatus.Success,
                        redirectUrl: Url.Action("Detail", "SaleInvoice")
                        );
                }
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    return JsonResponse(ex.Message, status: AjaxResponseStatus.Error);
            //}
        }
```

ConfigFile

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Exception</h2>

<hgroup>
    <h1>Error Occured </h1>
    <h1 class="alert alert-danger">An unknown error occurred while processing your request.</h1>
</hgroup>
```

I have Implement Custom Exception in asp.net mvc but i not working .. not show view having detail of exception ..view name 'Exception'......................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Are you hitting the filter? Is view in Shared folder?

Comment: yes  view in Shared folder